# How do you do a for loop in Python that cycles through input fields in html and checks their values

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am pretty new to python and am trying to make a web application. I have prior experience working performing this task using JavaScript but am not sure how I can do it in Python. Below is the JavaScript implementation of what id like to achieve:

```
    var tag = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
        if (tag[i].value.trim() == "" || tag[i].value == null || tag[i].value.match(/^(First Name|Last Name|Username|Password|Confirm Password|Email)$/)) {
            //Do something
        } else {
            
        }
    }
```

The only thing I could come up with is this:

```
    #Although this only finds the element, not its value
    tag = soup.find_all("input", {"class":"input"}) 
    
    for i in tag:
        if(i == "" or i == null or i.match(r'/^(First Name|Last Name|Username|Password|Confirm Password|Email)$/')):  
            print("Please Enter All fields")
            return render_template('login.html')
        else:
            #do something else
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Did you run your code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: What problem are you facing BTW?

Comment: There's no `null` in Python, so you probably should change that part to `None`.